# Do Exclusive load and store arm instruction raise a deadlock?

Tags: c, linux, arm, kernel, deadlock

Do Simple Spin Lock raise a deadlock that be cause by exclusive memory access instruction?

I have a idea about that **LDXR/STXR** occur a deadlock.
Is this case possible?

Two core access global variable in a few of instruction clock difference.
And repeat. Both cores is running same code.

My Exclusive Simple Spin Lock Assembly(Image):

```
.spin_lock:
    NOP
.stxr_fail:
    LDXR  R0, .data+0
    CMP   R0, #0
    BNE    .spin_lock
    MOV  R0, #1
    STXR  W0, R0, .data+0
    CMP   W0, #0
    BNE   .stxr_fail
    BL       critical_section()
    MOV  R0, #0
    STR     R0, .data+0
    RET 

.data:
    .word lock
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgGx1.png)

Do a deadlock occur on multi-core running? (Image):

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y42Ln.png)

Each line of the same color is atomic step. 
It operates sequentially in numerical step. 
This is occurred a deadlock by 6~11 steps.

If I misunderstand, Please kindly explain

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the **code in the question post** itself, not in the *linked image*. Please, fix that issue. Also, instead of colored arrows and numbers, which are uncleared, use some *textual notation* for explain the trace of execution.

Comment: I got this message when I post Image.: "You need at least 10 reputation to post images." T.T

Comment: No, you needn't to post an *image*. You need to post the code as a **text**. For format this text as a code, use `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried to write it in text, but because of the possibility of misunderstanding the execution flow sequence, I expressed it as images. I will remember your answer next time.

Comment: @old_timer Wow!! If so, do I have to write instructions with the deadlock in mind? in deadline scheduling?

Comment: 1. It is a **requirement** of the Stack Overflow to have the code as a text. 2. Replacing "image1" with a code definitely wouldn't introduce a misunderstanding. 3. You may have **both** textual code and an image in the question post. Just make sure that the textual code is clear. 4. Your "image2" is unclear by itself.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm sorry I don't know the rules of stackoverflow. A little updated. Thanks a lot for teaching me.

Comment: @old_timer! Thank you very very much! I asked because I could not imagine that a deadlock would occur for an exclusive access. I thought it would have been designed so that it would not happen, even in very short time, very low probability.

Comment: @old_timer: "... the memory unit sees load load store store and neither gets exclusive access." - in that case the first `store` will **succeed**: *exclusive-access* tag is cleared only when the other process **writes** to the given memory cell. The tag isn't cleared when other process just *reads* the cell.

Comment: Yep, I stand corrected, sorry.

Comment: @Tsyvarev! Can some proccesses be state to exclusive access tag at the same time??

Comment: Yes, nothing prevents several processes to *exclusive-access* tag the same memory cell at the same time.

Comment: @Tsyvarev. Thank you very much! I finally understood it by your comments and old_timer's comments and arm developer official site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load exclusive is going to check for a zero then try again until it is zero.

```
.spin_lock:
    NOP
.stxr_fail:
    LDXR  R0, .data+0
    CMP   R0, #0
    BNE    .spin_lock
```

If not zero then you end up with a

```
load exclusive
store exclusive
check if the store worked.
repeat the whole thing if not.
```

If two masters A and B were to perfectly line up

```
loadx a
loadx b
storex a
storex b
```

> Between the Exclusive Read and the Exclusive Write there can be other
> Non-exclusive transfers.

...

> If no other master has written to that location since the Exclusive
> Read transfer, the Exclusive Write transfer is successful and updates
> memory.

...

> If another master has written to that location since the Exclusive
> Read transfer, the Exclusive Write transfer is failed and the memory
> location is not updated.

the storex from master a would succeed, the storex from master b would fail so master a would exit the loop.  master b will continue to loop until the load returns non-zero.

So it can't deadlock even for a little bit.

I would have to read some more to confirm that loadx a, loadx b, storex a would have a valid store.  From the quotes above that would be the case.  If not then you would be in a situation where neither would obtain lock until such time as one gets interrupted or for any other reason changes its beat frequency possibly allowing the other master to get a clean load store exclusive. For example can the logic simply remember the id of the last ldrex and compare that to the next strex

> The Exclusive Access Monitor must be capable of concurrently
> monitoring at least one address location for each Exclusive access
> capable master in the system.

...

> A slave that does not support exclusive accesses can ignore the AxLOCK
> signals. It must provide an OKAY response for both normal and
> exclusive accesses. A slave that supports exclusive access must have
> monitor hardware. This specification recommends that such a slave has
> a monitor unit for each exclusive-capable master ID that can access
> it. The ARM Architecture Reference Manual, ARMv7-A and ARMv7-R edition
> defines an exclusive access monitor, and a single-ported slave can
> have such an exclusive access monitor external to the slave. A
> multiported slave might require internal monitoring.

What that means is that if the slave supports exclusive access then it must have a monitor (must store the id from a prior ldrex and compare it to the current strex).  but it is only recommended that it have a monitor per master, so if it doesn't have a monitor per master then you likely end up in a situation like this

ldrex a, ldrex b, strex a, strex b.   The ldrex b and strex a don't match so the store doesn't happen, now in that case the ldrex b and strex b do match so we would assume that master b gets the lock leaves the loop master a has to wait for master b to zero the memory location (clrex or perhaps a simple str).

Arm has axi and ahb bus specifications as well as different revisions of these specifications and which one goes with which core is perhaps in the technical reference manual for that core.  And to get the complete answer you should at least try to match these up and read the right revision spec for the core you are using and not assume that they all are exactly the same. Also understand the L1 cache is part of the arm core, the l2 cache is outside the core but you can buy an l2 from arm (or make your own) one would hope that ARMs logic supports exclusive access as documented.

Beyond that you are into the chip vendors territory and they can implement what they want broken or not, to truly share one would want these accesses to be in a common memory space shared by the various cores and not having the L1 or L2 cache answer and have coherency problem. The chip vendor may choose not to support exclusive access and will return OKAY. What that looks like to code like this is it will spin forever, the "return value" from the strex only passes on an EXOKAY if that is never returned because the design does not support exclusive access then the loop is infinite.  Been there, seen this, that's how I know. An older document said that exclusive access support was not required for uniprocessor designs, current versions of the specs do not say that they simply say things related to if the slave supports or doesn't support exclusive access then.

If the ldrex/strex lock is going to work you have to be working against a slave that supports exclusive access in that case you have a single monitor or a monitor per master and I believe I have shown the worst cases above if you get really really really lucky ldrex a, ldrex b, strex a, strex b for two masters a and b and one should win on that first pass through. And the other gets stuck waiting as desired/designed. Add more masters and mix the loads and stores from them and you end up with the same situation, one will win the others will lose and go into the ldrex not zero loop.  now interestingly if you have two or more of them in that loop then when the one master that has lock releases it you don't need to be all that lucky for the others competing for the lock to get a load load store store situation.

Comment: Hmm. I see... So, Is not global monitor changed to the open state from the exclusive state by new load or exclusive load at between a exclusive load to a exclusive store???

Comment: if you have one monitor then for that to work only the last ldrex id would be remembered and if the next strex has the same id then they match.  But this is implementation defined.  arm recommends you have a monitor per id, so ldrex a, ldrex b, strex a strex b.  the a and b monitors would record the ldrexes  the strex a lets assume works that resets any pending ldrexes (so the ldrex b is forgotten and the strex b fails).  a single monitor could not look at the id but in a multicore system that would fail.  so we would have to speculate as to a design for a single global monitor.

Comment: we would also hope no bugs in the design from the chip vendor (or arm for that matter), on the chip vendor side it would be part and stepping and we would hope there is an errata (and even worse that someone applied the errata correctly to an open source operating system, I have seen that done very badly with linux).  arm errata is not always available to the general public.  if it is all done in a sane matter and there is a functionally correct monitor or set of and of course exclusive support then this code will work in one pass for the winner.

Comment: if no exclusive support then your code/operating system hangs in this loop making it easy to detect the problem.  (been there seen that)

Comment: you really should go to infocenter.arm.com yourself and give up an email address and download the technical reference manual(s) and the axi spec(s) (under amba perhaps amba/axi with some versions have to dig into that directory a little).  and read it yourself and draw your own conclusions.  at the end of the day it should either be not supported (at some layer) or supported such that the code you posted works.  one core should win first time through the others should get stuck in the ldrex loop and then one of those should win when the lock is released and so on.

Comment: continuing to read, no surprise, the masters can have more than one transaction id each, so do this fully you would need enough monitors/storage of ids to cover all the masters times the number of possible ids per.  basically you look at the edge of the core and see how many bits there are in the id, which we dont have access to.  the dots I have not read enough or connected are if a master has multiple ids how do we control that in software and maybe that is because I mostly focus on a particular armv6 mpcore1 and not the armv7-a which is more complicated.

Comment: was this a homework assignment or curiosity or desiging some code, while linux implementations are not all that great sometimes, then tend to be functional, so borrowing that knowledge/code, which in this case is taken directly from arm documentation, will function (if you are at a layer and an implementation that supports exclusive access).  Any chip vendor wanting to sell a chip and use linux today will have some sort of exclusive access support.  so just use this code as prescribed by arm.

Comment: thanks to the reminder from  Tsyvarev the winner should win the first time through if you happen to have more than one make an attempt at nearly/exactly the same time.  I had forgotten that an ldrex does not interrupt an ldrex/strex pair from another master, it is only a successful store (or a non-esclusive store) that will cause the strex to fail.

Comment: Thank you your advice! It is Very helpful to me!

Comment: Can I ask you about one more question? How do masters run if they exclusive access at exactly the same time?

Comment: exclusive access only means that there are some bus bits that indicate the access type.  the axi bus design is such that multiple things can be going on at the same time there are actually if you want to think about it between two and four separate busses , a read address bus a read data bus a write address bus and a write data bus.  to do a read you put a request out on the read address bus with an id, later that is acked, later than that on the read data bus the slave asks the master if it wants the data, ack and the data is taken.

Comment: so instruction fetches could be going on at the "same time" that a program is doing accesses for example the requests and responses can be mixed on these busses by design.  an exclusive access is no different than an normal access except that some signals on the bus are different that are specific to the access type.  and some handshaking on the write that may or may not be special would have to look at it (you can too).

Comment: so each master ultimately lands on the external to the core axi bus which the chip vendor connects up to and needs to be able to keep track of and perform some number of transactions in flight, arguably could complete one transaction at a time and that wouldnt be strange nor wrong depends on the busses in the rest of the chip which is the chip vendors problem.  so on one clock cycle master a could do a read  request with exclusive bits set and the next clock cycle master b could do a read request with exclusive bits asserted.  then at some point the slave acks those then at some point...

Comment: completes those.

Comment: this is not some special arm thing their implementation is theirs but the days of a simple read/write line address and data lines are over for higher performance systems, you need to have busses that at least can start multiple transactions in flight at the same time, how the backend implements that plus any system rules (Dram is very slow, so if a uart status register read comes in AFTER a dram read, but we could possibly design it such that the uart read could start without waiting, does that break the overall architecture of the system?  answer is it depends)

Comment: x86 will bury this info in chip and within the company where ip vendors like arm at least expose it to the chip vendors that buy the ip.  some will be under nda others like arm you can download or google for how it works.

Comment: in no way shape or form does it take one clock to do something like a read or write like you might see on a microcontroller today or on an 8088/86 running with sram. if you get out to the axi it is several clocks at best, but like the pipeline in the processor this scheme relies on averages not individual transactions.  instead of the bus being tied up from start to finish for N number of clocks for one transaction, you break the transaction into parts and interleave the individual bus clocks for that transaction with possibly other transactions.

Comment: a read/write address data bus might have a wait state signal and the peripheral could hold onto that for a while making one transaction which is really two clocks to perform the request but N clock cycles were burned most of them dead time.